# Mathematica text keyword

Tags: mathematica-8

I have a file.txt looklike this

```
      key.txt
  date: Nov_17_12
  begin
     k 6.822379e+001 1.298165e+002 0.000000e+000
     k 0.000000e+000 1.298165e+002 0.000000e+000
     k 6.822379e+001 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000
  end

  begin
     k 6.822379e+001 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000
     k 0.000000e+000 1.298165e+002 0.000000e+000
     k 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000
  end

   begin
     k 6.822379e+001 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000
     k 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000
     k 1.456291e+002 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000
  end

  begin
     k 1.456291e+002 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000
     k 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000
     k1.456291e+002 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000
  end
```

So how can I convert it to MatrixForm as:

```
  A1 = {{6.822379e+001 1.298165e+002 0.000000e+000}
     {0.000000e+000 1.298165e+002 0.000000e+000}
     {6.822379e+001 7.357968e+001 0.000000e+000}}
```

A2 = bla bla